# Setting separate conditions for an alert to STOP firing

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I have an alert that fires when a metric exceeds a certain percent threshold (say, 90%), but it's making our alerting channel rather noisy.

Is there a way to define an alert to trigger when a metric passes one threshold (90%), but not to resolve until it returns to below a separate threshold (80%)?

Answer (score 1):

According with the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#number-of-notifications)

A notification is sent out each time series that causes a condition to be met. Another notification is sent when that time series no longer causes the condition to be met.

The policy resolves the incident when its conditions are no longer met (either because updated measurements no longer meet the conditions or because someone changes the policy's conditions).
Hence, your only option now is to modify your incident policy. On the other hand, you have an option to acknowledge an incident (but would not resolve it) per this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/incidents-events#acknowledging_incidents),  but the incident remains open until the conditions that triggered the incident are no longer true.

So, the option is not in GCP but I have created a Feature Request for Google on behalf of you, in order that they can add this functionality to their system: [Resolve an incident by a threshold](https://issuetracker.google.com/175230283), you could “star” the case to track any update on it.